# MySQL error when running an insert with a subselect?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run the following MySQL query:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (user_id, url_id, price_target)
VALUES 
(
select 1, URL_ID, min(price)
from table1
where price > 0
group by url_id
)
```

But get the error:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select 1, URL_ID, min(price) from table1 where price > 0 group by ' at line 4

Why? I run similar queries in Oracle all the time. If I run the subselect separate it selects the records as expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says "*check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use*".  Did you do that?  [`INSERT ... SELECT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html) is very clear:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (user_id, url_id, price_target)
select 1, URL_ID, min(price)
from table1
where price > 0
group by url_id
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I was following this: INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...) from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp which doesnt work

Comment: @AAA: That article describes the insertion of literal values; nowhere does it suggest putting a `select` statement within the parentheses of a `values` clause.

Comment: eggyal, you are correct. It would be too simple to make inserts of different varieties similar. thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

In using INSERT SELECT STATEMENT there is no need to add VALUES(). Please see revised script below.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (user_id, url_id, price_target)
SELECT 1, URL_ID, min(price)
FROM table1
WHERE price > 0
GROUP BY url_id;
```